# Hadoop MapReduce on Eclipse: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/myname183880112/.staging/job_local183880112_0001

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

```
2014-04-04 16:02:31.633 java[44631:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/04/04 16:02:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/04/04 16:02:32 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/04/04 16:02:32 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/04/04 16:02:32 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/04/04 16:02:32 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/04/04 16:02:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/myname183880112/.staging/job_local183880112_0001
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:950)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getLocalPath(JobConf.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:1013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at LineIndex.main(LineIndex.java:92)
```

I am trying to execute a Mapreduce program for Line Index using MapReduce in Eclipse. The above error shows up. My code is:

```
 public class LineIndex {

  public static class LineIndexMapper extends MapReduceBase
      implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private final static Text word = new Text();
    private final static Text location = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text val,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

      FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
      String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
      location.set(fileName);

      String line = val.toString();
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, location);
      }
    }
  }



  public static class LineIndexReducer extends MapReduceBase
      implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

      boolean first = true;
      StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();
      while (values.hasNext()){
        if (!first)
          toReturn.append(", ");
        first=false;
        toReturn.append(values.next().toString());
      }

      output.collect(key, new Text(toReturn.toString()));
    }
  }


  /**
   * The actual main() method for our program; this is the
   * "driver" for the MapReduce job.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(LineIndex.class);

    conf.setJobName("LineIndexer");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("output"));


    conf.setMapperClass(LineIndexMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(LineIndexReducer.class);
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

    client.setConf(conf);

    try {
      JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to understand and resolve the error Nullpointerexception here.
Could someone please help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Can you add mapred-site.xml file to the Configuration class object and try once more.
You may also need to specify the property `mapred.local.dir` in that xml file.